# Access filter of another column inside a column's Filter function?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

this is my column definition

```
columns: [
  {
    Header: "A",
    accessor: "a",
    id: "a",
    Cell: ({ value }) => value,
    filterMethod: (filter, row) => {
      // filter method
    },
    Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => {
      // how to access column B's selected filter here
      return (
       //component
      )
  },
  {
    Header: "B",
    accessor: "b",
    id: "b",
    Cell: ({ value }) => value,
    filterMethod: (filter, row) => {
      // filter method
    },
    Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => {
      return (
       //component
      )
  }
]
```

How to access another column's `filter value` in a column's `Filter: () => jsx_component`.

Here, in this Filter function I am getting three properties i.e, `column, filter and onChange`.`

`filter and onChange` are specific to this particular column..

> Now, how can I access filter of another column.

I need this to modify another filter component seeing the changes in one filter component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capturing filter changes in `onFilteredChange={(column, value) => {...}}`
and saving them to the state for use in another filter component did the trick.